prove that $\|f\|=1$, where $f : X\to X/\mathscr M$ is the projection
We define
$$B(X,Y)= \{ f \mid f:X \to Y, \text{ is continuous and linear function}\}$$
Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $\mathscr M \subset X $ be a closed subspace. Define
$$X/\mathscr M :=\{E_x \mid x\in X\}$$
Here $E_x=x+\mathscr M$ and
$$\|E_x\|=\inf \{\|y\| \mid y \in E_x\}.$$
We say that $f$ is linear bounded function if $ \exists M>0 : \forall x\in X, \|f(x)\| \le M\|x\| $. Also, we define this norm on $B(X,Y)$:
$$\|f\|:= \inf \{M>0 \mid \forall x\in X, \|f(x)\| \le M\|x\| \}.$$
We have proved that
$$\sup\{\|f(x)\| : \|x\| \le 1\} =\sup\{\|f(x)\| : \|x\| = 1\}=\sup\{\frac{\|f(x)\|}{\|x\|} : x \neq 0\} = \|f\|. $$
Let
$$f: X \to X/M , \ \ f(x)=E_x.$$
I tried to prove that |f|=1
$$\|f(x)\|=\|E_x\|=\inf \{\|y\| \mid y \in E_x\} \le \|x\| \Rightarrow \|f\| \le 1$$
I tried to prove that $\|f\| \ge 1$ by using the supremum definition but I couldn't. Any idea?

Let $E_x\neq 0$ in $X/\mathscr M$. Hence $\|E_x\|\neq 0$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there is $y\in E_x \subset X$ such that
$$ \| y\| \le (1+\epsilon) \| E_x\|.$$
Hence
$$ \| f(y)\| = \|E_y\| = \|E_x\| \ge \frac{\| y\| }{1+\epsilon},$$
this implies $\|f\| \ge (1+\epsilon)^{-1}$. Take $\epsilon\to 0$, one obtains $\|f\|\ge 1$.
